# Use multiple doctrine applications on single database

Tags: database, doctrine, symfony

I'm programming some applications in my company for internal use. I decided to create a central database which will serve data to Symfony applications with doctrine instances. How can I keep the doctrine entity configuration in sync with the database on changes?

Comment: I would keep data centralized, and access it through an API. This way you'll only need to maintain one set of entities for all your applications connecting through your API

Comment: Using the same database to manipulate entities across multiple applications sounds like bad practice because of synchronization issues you mentioned here, and also performance issues such as one application becoming slow because another has a lock on the database. I would suggest either limiting your applications to a monolith or changing the applications so that each is responsible for it's own database which contains all the data it needs to function.

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend for such a setup is to use entity packages which you host internally. That way your "api" are the repository classes. There are 2 solutions:

- You make 1 big package that contains all entities and solve a lot of headaches because you have everything, all the time. Which is another headache because you have to constantly update your package for each change you make.
- You make a bunch of tiny little packages. This will prevent you from making relations cross package though. Luckily you can use the [hostnet/entity-plugin-lib](https://github.com/hostnet/entity-plugin-lib), which uses generated traits to compose entities and glue functionality inside. This way your final entity will have the relations IF the package is available and installed in the application. Note that this is quite a difficult setup if you have little experience with php, entities or dependency management.